# ENCRYPTBYKEY sql server 2008 Only Encrypt First Character

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, encryption

I have problem with `ENCRYPTBYKEY` when I'm using a `SQL` parametrized query in an insert query. It only encrypts and decrypts the first character.

This is my code:

```
    sqlParameters[0, 0] = "@DatabaseVersion";
    sqlParameters[0, 1] = this.TextBox1.Text.Trim();

    queryString = "OPEN SYMMETRIC KEY Sym_password " +
                    "DECRYPTION BY CERTIFICATE Cert_Password WITH PASSWORD      = 'myPassword'" +
                    "Insert Into zz_database_version " +
                    "( " +
                    "  DatabaseVersion " +
                    ") " +
                    "Values " +
                    "( " +
                    "ENCRYPTBYKEY(KEY_GUID('Sym_password'), @DatabaseVersion)     " +
                    ") " +
                    "CLOSE SYMMETRIC KEY Sym_password";
```

Comment: check [this](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/616114/SQL-Server-T-SQL-Tips-Tricks#tips)

Comment: Thanks a lot but it NOT solution that i need

Comment: so did you try the code with SQL server directly? did you have same problem? bty why don't you a stored procedure buddy :)?

Comment: Thanks for your reply :) i don't know how to try it directly, i tied it without using parameters and it success..sorry i don't know ho to write good stored procedure and call it it try it out but i failed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

okay okay, open the SQL Server management studio, then create a new query panel `(ctrl+n)` and create the following stored procedure (F5 to run)

```
use mydb;--change the workstation to the desire database
go;
alter table zz_database_version alter column DatabaseVersion varbinary(8000) not null;--make sure the target field is varbinary too, if is, don't run this command
go;
create proc _encrypt(@data varchar(8000)) as begin
open symmetric key Sym_password certificate Cert_Password with password='myPassword'
insert zz_database_version(DatabaseVersion) select encryptbykey(key_guid('Sym_password'),@data);
close symmetric key Sym_password;
end
```

then in your C# code just call the procedure

```
SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection("Connection string here");
string sp = "_encrypt";
SqlCommand spcmd = new SqlCommand(sp, connection);
//
spcmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure 
//
SqlParameter theOrderID = new SqlParameter("@data", SqlDbType.String);
theOrderID = "The value needs to be encrypted";
SqlDataReader dr;
spcmd.Parameters.Add(theOrderID);
connection.Open();
spcmd.ExecuteScalar();
```

feedback for any failure or success :)

Comment: Thanks :))))))))))))))<br/> i will try it and inform you really really thank you.

Comment: I did not have any SqlDbType.String available.  I had to use SqlDbType.Char and set theOrderID.Size = "The value needs to be encrypted".Length

Answer (score 0):

Use `CONVERT` with data type and size of the value you are encrypting updating.
Looks like `EncryptByKey` does not recognize the data properly as per column schema.

Try as below

```
ENCRYPTBYKEY(KEY_GUID('Sym_password'), CONVERT(varchar(128),@DatabaseVersion))
```

*Assuming the @DatabaseVersion is of type varchar(128)*